# Java pattern to check text line

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching

I have a text line, and i read form android, i want to check if line is aceptable , the code will run.
Here my line

```
[al:Vol30]
[offset:0]

[00:37.00]3
[00:38.00]2
[00:39.00]1
[00:40.00]0/
```

So i want check line have pattern like this  [00:37.00]3
I create 1 pattern with this code:

```
String pattern = "^[d{2}:d{2}.d{2}].";
....
//check line
if(str.matches(pattern))
                {//do some thing}
```

How ever, this pattern is not correct so all line are fail. Can some one suggestion?

Comment: You need to escape square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String pattern = "^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{2}\\].";
```